# Conditional Regular Expression - Separate characters from dashes in URL and test if first character set (string) is numeric

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would you create a regular expression that would parse the following url

`http://example.com/answers/38-my-example-question-on-regular-expression`

Specifically, `"/answers/38-my-example-question-on-regular-expression"` versus `"/answers/category"`

If the regex finds "38" a number, then it does this:

```
RewriteRule answers/([-_~*a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/)?$ answers/view.php?title=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

else:

```
RewriteRule answers/([-_~*a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\/)?$ answers/categories.php?key=$1
```

I want to place the regex in the .httaccess for my webapp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule answers/([0-9]+)-?([-~a-zA-Z0-9/]*)/?$ answers/view.php?title=$2&id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule answers/([-~a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ answers/categories.php?key=$1
```

The two expressions - one looks for one or more numbers followed by a potential - and more characters to make up the title.  The other looks for anything else and calls it a category.